# prototype of function in JS?

Tags: javascript

See the code:

```js
function A(){
    
}
var x = new A();
console.log(x.attr);  // undefined
A.prototype.attr = 1; 
console.log(x.attr); // 1
```

The memory is allocated, when we invoke `new A()`, and x don't have property `attr`, but after `A.prototype.attr = 1;` is executed, x has property `attr`.
Does it mean `x` is reallocated?

Comment: No, x still references the same `A` object. Also, `x` doesn't have the property `attr`, that would be what would happen if you said `x.attr = 1`, which is not what you did. `x`'s *prototype* has the property `attr`, just like you wrote.

Comment: But the first time, I invoke `document.write(x.attr+"<br>"); `,  x's  prototype don't have property `attr`, so  x's  prototype is reallocated?

Comment: No, `x`'s prototype gets a new property. It's unclear what you mean by "reallocated" here.

Comment: if you want to understand it better, you should read this article: https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b

Comment: A literal reading of your question **cannot** be answered: whether or not a particular line of code triggers a reallocation is not only implementation dependent, but dependent on *how the program runs*. Is reallocation really what you're concerned with here?

Answer (score 2):

No. `x` is an instance of `A`. When you try to access `x.attr` initially, its prototype, `A`, does not have an attribute named `attr`. Thus, it is equivalent to calling `x.i_want_something_which_does_not_exist`, which returns `undefined`. But after you assign `A.prototype.attr`, all instances of `A` will share that value. For example,

```
function A(){

}
var x = new A();
var y = new A();
document.write(x.attr+"<br>");  // undefined
document.write(y.attr+"<br>");  // undefined
A.prototype.attr = 1; 
document.write(x.attr+"<br>"); // 1
document.write(y.attr+"<br>"); // 1
```

**Edit**: Here is an example of three instances:

```
function printValues(x, y, z){
  document.write("x.attr="+x.attr+", y="+y.attr+", z.attr="+z.attr+"<br />"); // Although I strongly recomment you to never use document.write
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice
}
function A(){

}
var x = new A();
var y = new A();
var z = new A();
printValues(x, y, z);

A.prototype.attr = 1; 
printValues(x, y, z);

y.attr = 2;
printValues(x, y, z);
```

produces:

```
x.attr=undefined, y=undefined, z.attr=undefined
x.attr=1, y=1, z.attr=1
x.attr=1, y=2, z.attr=1
```

Note that after running `y.attr=1`, `y.attr` has a different reference than `x.attr` and `z.attr`, which, by the way, still share same reference.

Comment: But you can set `y.attr=2;`, which means `attr` is not shared by `x` and `y`. So x have his own `attr`.

Comment: @gaussclb, I forgot to answer this. I've edited my answer to include this, thanks!

Comment: My bad, fixed it @gaussclb!

Answer (score 2):

Confusion is caused by **prototypical inheritance**. x in itself doesn't have a property **attr**. Which can be verified by running the following:

```
x.hasOwnProperty('attr')
```

This will return **false**.

However **x.attr** references the **attr** property assigned to **A.prototype**.

To see that try to console log

```
x.__proto__
```

**attr** property will be visible there.

Comment: Do you mean when we execute `A.prototype.attr = 1; ` All existed instances of `A` will add `attr` to `instance.__proto__`?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to add to every **instance**. By default `instance.__proto__` is referencing `A.prototype`. So there is only one **attr** property which is used by all instances

Answer (score 0):

You just add property `attr` to prototype object of `A`. When you call `x.attr` it firstly try to find it in own properties of `x`, and if can't find there - go to prototype of 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Matheus Pitz. After I read [Prototypes in JavaScript](https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b), I get the perfect answer.

- A.prototype is shared by all instances of A. When `new A()` is executed, `A().__proto__` is created, and refer to `A.prototype`. So when we add `attr` to `A.prototype`, all instances of `A` don't change.
- When we change `attr` of a instance, it doesn't change `instance.__proto__.attr`, it add `attr` to instance.

See the example:

```
function A(){

}
var x = new A();
var y = new A();
A.prototype.attr = 1; 

console.log(x.__proto__ === A.prototype) //true
console.log(y.__proto__ === A.prototype) //true
A.prototype.attr = 2; 
document.write(x.attr+"<br>"); // 2
document.write(y.attr+"<br>"); // 2

x.attr = 3;
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty('attr')) //true,attr=3
console.log(x.__proto__) //attr=2
document.write(x.attr+"<br>"); // 3
document.write(y.attr+"<br>"); // 2
```